# How to make Rscript stay open until gWidgets gui is closed

Tags: r, rscript

I have a script which launches various `gWidgets` windows with buttons that have functions attached.  I'd like to be able to launch this with rscript.exe so others can use it without seeing R.  My problem is that when I launch the script using `rscript.exe myscript.r` an rscript instance shows up in task manager, it loads all the packages, the widget pops up for a second, and then it's gone (including the rscript process from task manager) before the user can even do anything.  How can I make the instance of `rscript` stay active until all the `gWidgets` windows are closed?  If I launch the script from either Rstudio or Rgui it stays open until done.  As a similar question, is there also a way to prevent the dialog box showing the various commands from coming up too?  I'm using Windows 7 by the way.

Comment: See for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r/15283106#15283106 though you need to adapt for gWidgets.