# Plot columns in a data frame separately in a sequence

Tags: r, plot

I want to do some preliminary data analysis by looking at plots of each column in a data frame.  I want each column to be plotted separately, and I want to be able to toggle to the next column when I'm ready.

I tried:

```
graphics.off()
for (i in 2:251){
  stocks[,i]
{
  plot(stocks[,i])
}}
```

....however, this results in a really fast slide show, so I don't have time to look at each plot separately.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
graphics.off()
for (i in 2:251){
  stocks[,i]
{
  plot(stocks[,i])
  n <- readline("press enter to move: ")
}}
```