# How to read any keypress in interactive R (e.g. cursor-up or shift)?

Tags: r, device, keypress, interactive

How do you read any arbitrary keypress in R (interactive-mode), such as cursor-up or shift, and return the actual key(s) pressed?

Ideally in a device-independent, OS-independent way (I'm on Mac OS 10.8.x)

I'm talking about reading any actual arbitrary keypress including cursor-keys or modifier-keys, so `scan()` and `readline()` won't do it - cursor-keys get intercepted by the interactive console. And not just [waiting for a keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r).

It's not clear this is easy or device-independent. I looked at documentation:
`interactive()`, `options('device')`, R_INTERACTIVE_DEVICE, R_DEFAULT_DEVICE

I read [R-internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html), which says *"a graphics device... can handle requests/opportunities to take action such as... wait for an event, for example a mouse click or keypress."* but it doesn't say much more.

I tried `grDevices::getGraphicsEvent()` but got:

```
> getGraphicsEvent('waiting for cursor keys', onKeybd=function(key) { print(key) } )
Error in setGraphicsEventEnv(which, as.environment(list(...))) : 
  this graphics device does not support event handling
```

It seems like if you dig deep enough you could use a toolkit-specific and/or OS-specific hack, e.g. with Quartz. [This guy](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/108em88rj7/r-detecting-a-key-press) suggests `Sudoku::playSudoku()`, which uses Quartz to handle mouse and key input. I have Quartz. But a Quartz-specific solution won't work on Windows. This all seems quite messy.

Can someone please demystify all this?

Comment: I wondered whether Shiny would have anything for this, and found https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/events-keyboard.R from ggvis, not sure if that's any use or inspiration to you...

Comment: I think you need a GUI. The terminal just do not send anything to the R process when you only press the shift key for instance.

Comment: ping, Karl Forner et al: please give specific names of packages/functions, if you can?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this.  I can only get this to work with Windows and not mad @smci

Comment: The consensus I got from many R users was there is no platform-independent way to do this, and you have to use some device- and OS-specific functions, if they even exist on your platform. Really yukky. Might as well use Shiny for a GUI. Or use something other than R. @MadmanLee

Comment: That is a big bummer.  For R to remain competitive, development needs to be equal in both windows and mac.  All guis i developed in windows work great, but in mac only the "locator" functions works.