# R readline in non-interactive processing

Tags: r, readline, interactive

I want to write a R script, where I give an input at some point. I want to run it in Rstudio.
I do:

```
print("hi")
readline("Press a key to continue")
print("ho")
```

But the script does not stop and readline returns "".

I figured it is probably because my session is not "interactive". Is there a readline which will work for non-interactive processing? Or can I make my script interactive?

EDIT:

[How to wait for a keypress in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r) is not a duplicate, I even use the method "readline" stated in the accepted answer in my minimal failing example.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933024/8366499) discusses using `scan` in non-interactive mode. If that doesn't solve your question, you should give us more details on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The help for `readline` says: *In non-interactive use the result is as if the response was RETURN and the value is "".* This is exactly what you observe in your example...