# Recursion error in R (Fibonacci sequence)

Tags: r, stdin, rscript

So I am trying to learn R on my own and am just working through the online tutorial. I am trying to code a recursive function that prints the first n terms of the Fibonacci sequence and can't get the code to run without the error:

> Error in if (nterms <= 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

My code does ask me for input before entering the `if else` statement either which I think is odd as well. Below is my code any help is appreciated.

```
#Define the fibonacci sequence

recurse_fibonacci <- function(n) {
    # Define the initial two values of the sequence

    if (n <= 1){
        return(n)
    } else {

    # define the rest of the terms of the sequence using recursion
    return(recurse_fibonacci(n-1) + recurse_fibonacci(n-2))
    }
}

#Take input from the user
nterms = as.integer(readline(prompt="How many terms? "))

# check to see if the number of terms entered is valid
if(nterms <= 0) {
    print("please enter a positive integer")
} else {

    # This part actually calculates and displays the first n terms of the sequence
    print("Fibonacci Sequence: ")
    for(i in 0:(nterms - 1)){
        print(recurse_fibonacci(i))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry apr92 but I cannot replicate any problems. The example works fine on my system.

Comment: If I copy-paste his entire code chunk into my console, I get a similar error, presumably because what's pasted immediately after the `readline` command is interpreted as (an invalid) `nterms`.

Comment: The error mentioned by op happens only if you copy and paste the relevant code to the terminal.

Comment: Really? Because this is the second time I have gotten errors that others don't get. I was told the first time to highlight the whole code then hit run which fixed it that time but didn't help this time. What system are you using?

Comment: @apr92 If you simply run this code from the RStudio environment or any text editor, instead of copy-pasting into the command line or console, it should work.

Comment: R4.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. No erros here. And I have copy-pasted the code into RStudio. This should also work on RGui/Windows.

Comment: Save the code in file, `fib.R`, then from an R shell you can do `source ("fib.R")`

Comment: infinitefactors: Do you know why it would interpret nterms. as invalid? especially when I was not asked to input a number when i hit run?

Comment: @phoxis `Rscript fib.R` gives the error in the question.

Comment: As soon as the line defining `nterms` is executed, the expression that comes immediately after will be assigned to `nterms`. So if you copy-paste that whole thing in one go, it'll think that whatever line comes after that is `nterms` -- it won't "wait" for you to supply a valid `nterms` before running the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried it in RStudio but got the same error. I typed the code in notepad and opened that in RStudio but no luck either.

Comment: but if the line defining nterms is executed shouldnt it prompt me for input before moving on?

Answer (score 2):

To make it work with `Rscript` replace

`nterms = as.integer(readline(prompt="How many terms? "))`

with

```
cat ("How many terms?")
nterms = as.integer (readLines ("stdin", n = 1))
```

Then you can run it as `Rscript fib.R`, assuming that the code is in the file `fib.R` in the current working directory.

Otherwise, execute it with `source ("fib.R")` within an R shell.

Rscript does not operate in interactive mode and does not expect any input from the terminal. Check what `interactive ()` returns in both the cases. Rscript will return FALSE as it is non-interactive, but the same function when run within an R shell (with `source ()`) it will be true.

`?readline` mentions that it cannot be used in non-interactive mode. Whereas `readLines` explicitely connect to stdin.

Comment: So your saying that I cannot use readlines while in interactive mode?

Comment: @apr92 In interactive mode you can use `readlines` . Check `?readlines`

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of `readline` in non-interactive mode. `readline` does not wait for a keypress and immediately executes the next instruction. The solution below is the solution posted in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22933024/8245406).

I post below a complete answer, with the Fibonnaci numbers function a bit modified.

```
recurse_fibonacci <- function(n) {
  # Define the initial two values of the sequence
  if (n <= 1){
    n
  } else{
    # define the rest of the terms of the sequence using recursion
    Recall(n - 1) + Recall(n - 2)
  }
}

#Take input from the user
cat("How many terms?\n")
repeat{
  nterms <- scan("stdin", what = character(), n = 1)
  if(nchar(nterms) > 0) break
}
nterms <- as.integer(nterms)

# check to see if the number of terms entered is valid
if(nterms <= 0) {
  print("please enter a positive integer")
} else {
  # This part actually calculates and displays the first n terms of the sequence
  print("Fibonacci Sequence: ")
  for(i in 0:(nterms - 1)){
    print(recurse_fibonacci(i))
  }
}
```

This code is the contents of file `fib.R`. Running in a Ubuntu 20.04 terminal gives

```
rui@rui:~$ Rscript fib.R
How many terms?
8
Read 1 item
[1] "Fibonacci Sequence: "
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
[1] 8
[1] 13
rui@rui:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
The error is gone however now there is a new problem: 
below the script in console it does display
all the code and after the cat() it does ask for me to input a number but then
it just moves on to the repeat loop and never seems to leave it which im pretty
sure means theres some kind of infinite loop. Like I said I am typing everything
in notepad and then running it in RStudio, don't know if that makes a difference
of not. I'm very new to this so sorry for the burden

Comment: update: hitting the source button only displays the message "How many terms?" but when I hit 8 it does not print the terms of the sequence

Comment: @apr92 Try removing the code lines `repeat` and `if(nchar(...))`.

Comment: ok I got it to work but I did have to change a couple of things from your code. Instead of using recall() like you did I stuck with return. I changed 
nterms = as.integer(readline("stdin", n = 1)) to nterms = as.integer(readline())
and i changed the counter in the for loop from 0:(nterms-1) to 0:(nterms) and now it works. I do have some questions about this though like why did you chose to use cat() instead of readline (), why did you chose to use recal instead of return, and in cat("How many terms?\n") why do you have the "\n"? Thanks again

Comment: @apr92 1) `cat` gives a nicer output, with no `[1]`. The final `\n` is the newline character. 2) `scan` is used instead of `readline` because R sends an empty `""` string to `readline` automatically without waiting for user input and executes the next instruction. `scan` can read from `stdin` and has an argument `n` where you can pass the number of input values to be read.

Comment: @apr92 3) There is no need for `return` since the function can return `n` or call itself recursively returning those values. `Recall` does precisely that and it seemed more readable to me. But if your code works, use it.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine but you shouldn't enter it into the terminal as is. My suggestion: put the code into a script file (ending .R) and source it (get help about it with `?source` but it's actually pretty straightforward).

In R-Studio you can simply hit the source button.