# continue code after press enter in console

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a code that will start running after pressing the enter key.
I looked at [the examples in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272916/how-to-wait-for-a-keypress-in-r) but it looks like they are outdated because they don't work for me..
Here is a simple example of my code

```
print_me_after_press <- "YYeeeess!!!"
invisible(readline("Press [enter] "))
print(print_me_after_press)
```

The problem is that the code does not wait for me to press enter, but immediately prints `"YYeeeess!!!"`

Comment: I just typed in a semi-colon-separated string of that and it worked: `print_me_after_press <- "YYeeeess!!!";invisible(readline("Press [enter] "));print(print_me_after_press)`, the string was printed only after I pressed enter.

Comment: for me, its another case of different behaviour in R using the terminal and Rstudio

Comment: @r2evans It didn't work for me((.

    But if I pack all  code into a function, then my original code works